# Pause a streaming radio through web services

Tags: c#, web-services, audio-streaming, naudio, internet-radio

I have a probleme once I start playing the radio th pause function doesn't work this is my code

```
public class player
{
   Stream ms = new MemoryStream ( );
   WaveStream blockAlignedStream;
   IWavePlayer waveOut = new WaveOut ( WaveCallbackInfo . FunctionCallback ( ) );`

   public void play ( string url )
    {

       new Thread ( delegate ( object o )
       {
           // http://www.samisite.com/sound/cropShadesofGrayMonkees.mp3
           var response = WebRequest . Create ( url ) . GetResponse ( );
           using ( var stream = response . GetResponseStream ( ) )
           {
              byte[] buffer = new byte [ 65536 ]; // 64KB chunks
              int read;
              while ( ( read = stream . Read ( buffer , 0 , buffer . Length ) ) > 0 )
                {
                   var pos = ms . Position;
                   ms . Position = ms . Length;
                   ms . Write ( buffer , 0 , read );
                   ms . Position = pos;
                }
            }
    } ) . Start ( );

    // Pre-buffering some data to allow NAudio to start playing
    while ( ms . Length < 65536 * 5 )  // *10
        Thread . Sleep ( 1000 );

    ms . Position = 0;

    blockAlignedStream = new BlockAlignReductionStream ( WaveFormatConversionStream . CreatePcmStream ( new Mp3FileReader ( ms ) ) ); 
    this.waveOut . Init ( blockAlignedStream );
    this.waveOut . Play ( );
    while ( waveOut . PlaybackState == PlaybackState . Playing )
        {
        System . Threading . Thread . Sleep ( 100 );
        }
    } 
public void stop ( ) 
  {
   this.waveOut . Stop ( );
   this.waveOut . Dispose ( );
   this.waveOut = null;  
   }
```

then I call it for a webmethode like this

```
player mp3=new player ( );
[WebMethod]
 // http://streaming.radio.funradio.fr/fun-1-44-128

public void play(string url)
{
   mp3.play ( url );
}
[WebMethod]
public void pause (  )
{
   mp3 .pause();
}
```

some times a screen message show this error: "WaveOut device was not closed at WaveOut.Finalize()"

I have found the probleme when I launch the pause function it uses the parametre "waveOut" as it's not modified in the play function I need to find a way to get the connection between them. Any ideas !!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an approach I would recommend for playing streaming MP3 files. I'm amazed it works at all, since the MP3 File Reader in NAudio tries to build a table of contents, and you are trying to read and write a memory stream on two different threads.

The NAudio demo app shows how I would recommend going about doing this. You parse and decode MP3 frames as they are received and place them into a BufferedWaveProvider, which is used to play from. Optionally, you can pause playback if you don't have enough buffered audio. The source code is available from [naudio.codeplex.com](http://naudio.codeplex.com)

Comment: I have to use this approach because I'm building a radio server. And I'm already using the example from codeplex and trying to adapte it for my needs